# MSQL: Left join with select statement

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have one main table project application as A (keeping many years application).

I have one table keeping state of project A called B. One project can have many state.

Table C keeping the reference of the state.

Looks pretty simple.

Application for year 2023 is 9265. Table B grows up to 59,448 records.

When i want to do SQL, i use like this:

```
select 
A.reference
,A.project_name
,D.allstate
from A as A
left join 
     (select 
      B.id_A as id
      , group_concat(C.state_name) as allstate 
      from B as B
      left join C as C on C.state_id = B.state_id
      group by B.id_A) as D on D.id = A.id
where A.year_apply='2023'
```

and i have **many other left join as D**, making the result takes longer time to produce.

Is there any other ways i can improve my SQL?

The result of explain analyze is as below:

```
-> Nested loop left join  (actual time=183.764..195.213 rows=9265 loops=1)
    -> Index lookup on A using year (year=2023)  (cost=929.01 rows=9265) (actual time=0.108..2.078 rows=9265 loops=1)
    -> Index lookup on D using <auto_key0> (id=A.id)  (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=9265)
        -> Materialize  (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=1 loops=9265)
            -> Group aggregate: group_concat(group_concat(C.name separator ',')  (actual time=37.868..155.349 rows=27009 loops=1)
                -> Nested loop left join  (cost=9539.50 rows=21145) (actual time=37.832..94.325 rows=59448 loops=1)
                    -> Sort: B.id_A  (cost=2138.75 rows=21145) (actual time=37.807..42.434 rows=59448 loops=1)
                        -> Table scan on B  (actual time=0.068..22.110 rows=59448 loops=1)
                    -> Single-row index lookup on C using PRIMARY (state_id=B.state_id)  (cost=0.25 rows=1) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=59448)
```

I notice the looping is longer because it always will query all data in B. I only specify where condition (year_apply = 2023) outside of the loop. May I know how to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your query doing filtering before aggregation

```
select 
    reference
    , project_name
    , group_concat(state_name) allstate
from (select distinct
        A.reference
        , A.project_name
        , A.id 
        , C.state_name
    from A 
        left join B on B.id_A = A.id 
        left join C on C.state_id = B.state_id
    where A.year_apply='2023') as temp 
group by reference, project_name;
```

---

Edit addressing "I need to query many fields and many left join as D"

If your multiple fields are somehow related, you can use this structure:

```
select 
    reference
    , project_name
    , group_concat(state_name) allstate
    , group_concat(state_name2) allstate2
from (select distinct
        A.reference
        , A.project_name
        , A.id 
        , C.state_name
        , C2.state_name state_name2
    from A 
        left join B on B.id_A = A.id 
        left join C on C.state_id = B.state_id
        left join C2 on C2.state_id = B.state_id 
    where A.year_apply='2023') as temp 
group by reference, project_name;
```

otherwise, if it would create too many rows, you need to take the compromise of performance and code simplicity

```
select 
    t1.reference
    , t1.project_name
    , t1.allstate
    , t2.allstate allstate2 
from (select 
        reference
        , project_name
        , id
        , group_concat(state_name) allstate
    from (select distinct
            A.reference
            , A.project_name
            , A.id 
            , C.state_name
        from A 
            left join B on B.id_A = A.id 
            left join C on C.state_id = B.state_id
        where A.year_apply='2023') as temp 
    group by reference, project_name ) t1
join (select 
        reference
        , project_name
        , id 
        , group_concat(state_name) allstate
    from (select distinct
            A.reference
            , A.project_name
            , A.id 
            , C2.state_name
        from A 
            left join B on B.id_A = A.id 
            left join C2 on C2.state_id = B.state_id
        where A.year_apply='2023') as temp 
    group by reference, project_name ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id ;
```

Or, third option could be to change how you extract your data, either by changing data structure / adding lookup tables, or by extracting only raw data and making aggregation in another tool.

Comment: thanks @Máté Juhász. The query above is just a sample. I need to query many fields and many left join as D. I try to avoid group from main query as the data will be huge with other left join..

Comment: @wanna please see my edited solution

Comment: okay. i will digest it first.=)